# How to find $T(u) = 0$ given pole of Mobius transformation

Tags: mobius-transformation

Suppose that $T$ is a Mobius transformation that maps the unit circle unto itself. Given that the pole of the map is $2 + i$ (So, $T(2 + i) = ∞$). Find a point $u$ that gets mapped to zero (So, $T(u) = 0$).

I know that Mobius transformation can be defined by three points, which I used as $-1 \, \text{and} \, 1$ on the unit circle, and then use the fact that the denominator will equal 0. So I get something along the lines of

$T(z) = \frac{az + b}{z - (2 + i)}$

Am I using the correct approach? How do I use this to find $T(u) = 0$?

Comment: There exists a characterization of coefficients $a,b,c,d$ such that the Möbius transformation $z\mapsto \frac{az*b}{cz+d}$ sends the unit circle $|z|=1$ into itself. You are right about the constraint on $a,b,c,d$ given by the pole condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Möbius transformation mapping the unit *disc* to itself is a Poincaré disc transformation [and has the form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Subgroups_of_the_M%C3%B6bius_group)
$$T(z)=e^{i\phi}\frac{z+b}{\bar bz+1}$$
Since here $\bar b(2+i)+1=0$, $b=\overline{-1/(2+i)}=-\frac25-\frac15i$ and the point sent to zero is $-b=\frac25+\frac15i$.

However the transformation here is only required to map the unit circle to itself. Thus the inverse form is also possible:
$$T(z)=e^{i\phi}\frac{\bar bz+1}{z+b}$$
But we get the same result for the root of $T$ in this case.

Comment: Since $T$ is only required to map the unit *circle* to itself, a second solution is $T(z)=e^{-i\phi}\frac{(2-i)z+1}{z-(2+i)}$, with the same point sent to $0$.